# How to extract total search results with Selenium Webdriver in Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to extract the search results count from an IEEE Xplore search given the search results URL using the selenium webdriver.
I'm not getting any errors from the code below, but I am unsure how to proceed from here.

Website Element of Interest:
[image: Website Element of Interest]

Element Inspection Results:
[image: Element Inspection Results]

```
url = 'https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/search/searchresult.jsp?newsearch=true&queryText=web%20scraping'
chrome_driver_path = '\\xxxx\chromedriver.exe'
driver.get(url)
wait.until(presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "strong")))
#result = driver.??????
print(result)
driver.close()
```

Comment: Honestly, will be better to try first their API endpoint to get this data. You can open devtools in your browser, Network tab and then find a POST request to the `https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/rest/search` endpoint

Comment: @dukkee Thank you for the response. I've considered this, but this is in-part a learning exercise for scraping in general for me and since it's for personal use, I don't have a website or company affiliation for their API application form.

Comment: what do you mean by "their API application form"? Internal API usage is the same scraping as layout scraping.

Answer (score 1):

To print the number of search results i.e.  *`184`* you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/search/searchresult.jsp?newsearch=true&queryText=web%20scraping")
  print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.Dashboard-header span span:nth-of-type(2) ").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `xpath` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  driver.get("https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/search/searchresult.jsp?newsearch=true&queryText=web%20scraping")
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'Dashboard-header')]//span//following::span[2]").text)
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  driver.get("https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/search/searchresult.jsp?newsearch=true&queryText=web%20scraping")
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.Dashboard-header span span:nth-of-type(2)"))).text)
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/search/searchresult.jsp?newsearch=true&queryText=web%20scraping")
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'Dashboard-header')]//span//following::span[2]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  184
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### References

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)

Answer (score 0):

As dukkee mentioned check the api, but to answer your question you can select it like:

```
soup.select('div.Dashboard-header.col-12 > span span')[1].get_text()
```

Locate a parent `div` with unique `class` and then go down to the `span`.

**Example**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

url = 'https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/search/searchresult.jsp?newsearch=true&queryText=web%20scraping'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
print(soup.select('div.Dashboard-header.col-12 > span span')[1].get_text())

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks for the process explanation. The example worked perfectly for me, though I am sometimes getting an "IndexError: list index out of range" error. It seems that the page doesn't always load, which causes this error. If I try the same search a bit later, it's working fine.

Comment: You can handle this even better with [Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) instead of `sleep` - Cause you can define to wait for a certain condition e.g. element is loaded and than proceed in the code.